# Using high definition pictures in android

Tags: android, image, gridview

I'm having some trouble when uploading high definition pictures in my app.
I have a Grid View and when I add the photo the app crashes stating that its a memory problem.

One solution I did was to decrease the size of the image through a website (https://www.befunky.com/create/resize-image/) but the image gets blurie. 
Also used a solution that is present on the official Android developers' website (https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html), unsuccessfully (the app gets too slow and I have the previous result).

I've seen many applications where this is not a issue and I want to learn the way they do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), it can load an image into your imageView from your drawable (or url), and its `fit()` method allows you to reduce the image to the lowest possible resolution, without affecting quality.

Basically, it measures the dimensions of the target ImageView and uses `resize()` to reduce the image size to the dimensions of your ImageView:

High quality picture in drawable folder:

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(R.drawable.image)
       .fit()
       .into(imageView);
```

High quality picture from a url:

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load("www.url.com/image.jpg")
       .fit()
       .into(imageView);
```

You can find more details on how to use fit, resizing and scaling with Picasso [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit).